Facebook Integration
Just starting to look at FB (and/or other social media) integration into SFMC.
I've been asked to investigate what work is involved in integrating our Marketing Cloud with social media, starting with FB. We want to be able (if possible) to import potential customers into a data extension to communicate to.
Can't see a lot out there if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. Has anyone recently done this? thanks, Ian

So, what integration do you need? For advertising, you can utilise Advertising Studio. For lead acquisition - you can use Lead Gen forms

thanks for the update. we are initially looking at FB. We don't seem to have Advertising Studio, not sure why. I will look into it.

If you provide more context beyond "looking at FB", it will be easier to give you a more comprehensive answer.

I've been asked to investigate what work is involved in integrating our Marketing Cloud with social media, starting with FB. We want to be able (if possible) to import potential customers into a data extension to communicate to. thanks

For lead acquisition, you should check out Lead Capture for SFMC. You should be careful, as this will just create records in a data extension, without observing your Subscriber Key of choice. Also, you will not be able to trigger any communication in real time.
In case you work in a cross cloud environment, where you have Sales Cloud as your system of record for leads and contacts, you should consider Lead Capture for Sales Cloud. This will create a lead directly in Sales Cloud, and you will be able to trigger an email in real time to this person, confirming lead form submission.

thanks Lukas. I will take a look at this option
